# Approximately matching time values in separate objects

Tags: r, time-series

I have two data frames that come from two separate analytics sources for the same website. I'm looking to match events in the first (df1) with the time signatures of events from the second (df2). Most events in df1 will not have a corresponding event in df2.

Hence, I'd like to be able to filter the events in df1 if there is a time match within 30 seconds from df2.

```
    df1 <- read.csv(text = "start_time, visit_duration
2017-08-13 12:13:53,22
2017-08-13 15:41:44,10
2017-08-13 16:03:45,11
2017-08-13 16:39:03,05")
df1$start_time = strptime(df1$start_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df2 <- read.csv(text = "timestamp
2017-08-13 12:11:53
2017-08-13 15:44:50
2017-08-13 16:03:59
2017-08-13 16:39:30")
df2$timestamp = strptime(df2$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

There should be 2 matches here for the 3rd and 4th events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `outer` to get the `difftime` and apply the 30 second requirement, i.e.

```
which(abs(outer(df1$start_time, df2$timestamp, `difftime`)) <= 30, arr.ind = T)[,1]
#[1] 3 4
```

Comment: this works and returns a list of row numbers.

For the benefit of others I managed to return just the events with matching row numbers with:

        df3 <- df1[which(abs(outer(df1$start_time, df2$timestamp, `difftime`)) <= 30, arr.ind = T)[,1],]